# How to hook hotkeys in winforms or WPF from a .NET 2.0 assembly?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, hotkeys, winforms-interop

I have assembly that targets .NET 2.0 to be compatible with a broad range of applications.  When used with a desktop application (either winforms or WPF) I want to hook certain hotkeys and popup modeless dialog windows.  The tricky bit is finding a solution that can be implemented under .NET 2.0 that is compatible with WPF.

For winforms I could  use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) or implement IMessageFilter and hook [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx) in the [PreFilterMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage.aspx) method, but they don't work well with WPF.

For WPF, the [InputBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding.aspx) class is very nice, but this isn't available in .NET 2.0.

An ideal solution would:

- Build in an assembly targeting .NET
- Hook keystrokes for either WPF or Winforms
- Provide application-wide, not system-wide scope

Answer (score 0):

You could build a universal solution based on Windows API (System wide hook). Don Esposito has written a great article on that. Here's a link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188966.aspx

You could write an application hook too if you don't want a system wide hook. That's actually easier to implement. Don covers that too I think.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great article, but it's from 2002 and doesn't discuss WPF interop which is really at heart of my problem.